# Converting zoo object

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, zoo

I have one zoo object and my intention is to convert data into data.frame.

```
#CODE
  #ZOO OBJECT
class(DATA_1ab)
#[1] "zoo"

  #CONVERTING INTO DATA FRAME
TEST1<-data.frame(coredata(DATA_1ab))
class(TEST1)
#[1] "data.frame"

  #NEW DATA FRAME
TEST1

     SALES   REVENUE
1    369.1   119.4  
4    595.2  123.4  
9    675.2   144.7  
13   383.7  498.8  
18   184.2   647.1   
23   279.4  145.1
```

After converting zoo object into data.frame I have other problem. Namely column before (column SALES)  have abnormal growth schedule (e.g 1,4,9,13,18,23 etc), so my question is how to fix this and get new data frame with normal growth schedule (e.g 1,2,3,4,5,6) like table below? I'm asking because I want to continue with this data.frame into ts object and so on...

```
    SALES   REVENUE
1   369.1   119.4  
2   595.2  123.4  
3   675.2   144.7  
4   383.7  498.8  
5   184.2   647.1   
6   279.4  145.1
```

Example of data with dput function for zoo object (DATA_1ab)

```
     structure(c(369.1, 595.2, 675.2, 383.7, 184.2, 279.4, 266.9, 
133.2, 419.7, 281.2, 276.5, 141.5, 298.2, 321.4, 298.1, 141.5, 
.5, 
119.4, 133, 405.4, 298.1, 57.8, 168.6, 435.3, 596, 136.6, 52.1, 
151.9, 542.9, 151.4, 188.2, 35.6, 229.7, 517.7, -37.9, 94.9, 
78.8, 658.9, 54.1, 156.8, 144.6, 649.4, 214.7, 379.6, 31.4), .Dim = c(157L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "4", "9", "13", "18", "23", "28", 
"33", "38", "43", "48", "53", "58", "63", "68", "73", "78", "82", 
"86", "91", "96", "100", "105", "110", "114", "119", "124", "128", 
"133", "138", "143", "147", "152", "157", "162", "167", "171", 
"176", "181", "186", "191", "195", "200", "204", "209", "214", 
"2016.02", "2016.03", "2016.04", "2016.05", "2016.06", "2016.07", 
"2016.08", "2016.09", "2016.10", "2016.11", "2016.12", "2016.13", 
"2016.14", "2016.15", "2016.16", "2016.17", "2016.18", "2016.19", 
"2016.20", "2016.21", "2016.22", "2016.23", "2016.24", "2016.25", 
"2016.26", "2016.27", "2016.28", "2016.29", "2016.30", "2016.31", 
"2016.32", "2016.33", "2016.34", "2016.35", "2016.36", "2016.37", 
"2016.38", "2016.39", "2016.40", "2016.41", "2016.42", "2016.43", 
"2016.44", "2016.45", "2016.46", "2016.47", "2016.48", "2016.49", 
"2016.50", "2016.51", "2016.52", "2017.01", "2017.02", "2017.03", 
"2017.04", "2017.05", "2017.06", "2017.07", "2017.08", "2017.09", 
"2017.10", "2017.11", "2017.12", "2017.13", "2017.14", "2017.15", 
"2017.16", "2017.17", "2017.18", "2017.19", "2017.20", "2017.21", 
"2017.22", "2017.23", "2017.24", "2017.25", "2017.26", "2017.27", 
"2017.28", "2017.29", "2017.30", "2017.31", "2017.32", "2017.33", 
"2017.34", "2017.35", "2017.36", "2017.37", "2017.38", "2017.39", 
"2017.40", "2017.41", "2017.42", "2017.43", "2017.44", "2017.45", 
"2017.46", "2017.47", "2017.48", "2017.49", "2017.50", "2017.51", 
"2017.52", "2018.01", "2018.02", "2018.03", "2018.04", "2018.05", 
"2018.06", "2018.07", "2018.08", "2018.09", "2018.10", "2018.11", 
"2018.12", "2018.13", "2018.14", "2018.15", "2018.16", "2018.17", 
"2018.18", "2018.19", "2018.20", "2018.21", "2018.22", "2018.23", 
"2018.24", "2018.25", "2018.26", "2018.27", "2018.28", "2018.29", 
"2018.30", "2018.31", "2018.32", "2018.33", "2018.34", "2018.35", 
"2018.36", "2018.37", "2018.38", "2018.39", "2018.40", "2018.41", 
"2018.42", "2018.43", "2018.44", "2018.45", "2018.46", "2018.47", 
"2018.48", "2018.49", "2018.50", "2018.51", "2018.52", "2018.53"
), class = "zoo")
```

Below is conversion into ts object.

```
  #CONVERTING INTO TS OBJECT
   WEEKLY_TS_REVENUES<-ts(TEST1,start=c(2016,1),frequency = 52)


WEEKLY_TS_REVENUES
Time Series:
Start = c(2016, 1) 
End = c(2019, 1) 
Frequency = 52 
          SALES   REVENUE
2016.000  369.1   119.4    
2016.019  595.2  123.4
2016.038  675.2  144.7
2016.058  383.7  498.8
2016.077  184.2  647.1
2016.096  279.4  145.1
```

First column of ts object is still irregular.

Comment: Does `rownames(TEST1) <- c(1:nrow(TEST1))` what you expect?

Comment: Тhis partly solves my problem.I try with your line of code and after that I put  data.frame TEST1 into ts function, but I still have same problem                             # WEEKLY_TS_REVENUES<-ts(TEST1,start=c(2016,1),frequency = 52). First column is still irregular (2016.000,2016.019,2016.038 etc)

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example by showing a little of your data? You can use `dput` for this purpose.

Comment: I've already entered the data with dput function.You can see up into edited question

Comment: The dput output is for a data frame but in the question you say the input is a zoo object.  Please fix.

Comment: I've already entered the data with dput function. You can see up into edited question for zoo object

Comment: There is something wrong with your DATA_lab dput output.  If I copy and paste it into R I get an error message. Please try again.  Before posting it I suggest you try copying and pasting it to ensure it works.

Comment: Please try again.Data is corrected.

Comment: Still having trouble with the data you've supplied - this is the error I am getting: 

 `Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) : 
      dims [product 314] do not match the length of object [45]`